# What's the official term for when the verb inverts or flips its Thematic Roles?

Tags: terminology, historical-linguistics, etymology

[Luke Sawczak](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/50807/luke-sawczak) referred to ["the other way around"](https://www.reddit.com/r/etymology/comments/rkx9rd/does_if_you_please_have_any_relation_to_sil_vous/hpcd5tz/),  as switching places.

> [Interestingly, in English, *like* and *please* appear to have switched places at some point in the past.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/138634)

["This change also happened with "think", as we all know the Renaissance "methinks" that became "I think" and is usually translated now as "it seems to me".](https://www.reddit.com/r/etymology/comments/rkx9rd/does_if_you_please_have_any_relation_to_sil_vous/hpcd5tz/)

I need to know the correct terminology, because I hanker to read more about this change. For example, why does this happen? What spurred this change? Why would laypeople swap semantic roles?

Comment: _Think_ didn’t switch. ‘Methinks’ is etymologically from the old base verb _þyncan_ ‘seem, appear’ in Old English, and ‘think’ is from the causative of that verb, _þencan_ ‘make sth. seem/appear [to oneself] > think’. The two verbs merged later on, with the base verb disappearing except in the now fixed word ‘methinks’. It seems to be a common development in Germanic languages that verbs dealing with appraising things do this: Norwegian _like_ has done the same as its English counterpart, as have Swedish _tycka_ (same word as _þyncan_) and Danish _synes_ and _tykkes_ (both ‘think’).

Comment: The [sense verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299) provide a good example. _Hear, listen,_ and _sound_ are 3 different types of verb -- _hear_ and _listen_ both have human agent subjects, but _listen_ is volitional, while _hear_ is non-volitional, just like the difference between _see_ and _look_. _Sound_, on the other hand, has a subject that refers to the source of the sensation, and a human involved only with a preposition _to_. There are a lot of such "flip predicates" if you look for them.